# suppose $\sum a_n$ converges. Is it true that then $\sum (-1)^na_n$ will

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

suppose $\sum a_n$ converges. Is it true that then $\sum (-1)^na_n$ will also converge.

I think that the statement is true but I'm having trouble proving it.

Comment: Do you know about absolute convergence?

Comment: so since it converges absolutely then $\sum (-1)^na_n$ will also converge? @Randall

Comment: abs cov says if $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges then so does $\sum_n a_n$.  That's exactly your situation.

Comment: @Randall that's not the situation because $a_{n}$ converging does not imply $|a_{n}|$ converging.

Comment: @Randall $|a_n| \neq a_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed $a_n$ was positive, I think.

Comment: Actually Randall that would be OP's situation if the $a_n$s are either all positive or all negative. We don't know that to be the case though. In fact, let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $\sum_n a_n$ converges but $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n = \sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ does not. So to answer OP's question, NO, $\sum_n a_n$ converging does not imply $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ converging. (If the $a_n$s are all positive or all negative then the answer is yes.)

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

Let consider

- $a_n=(-1)^{n}\frac1n\implies \sum a_n$ converges

but

- $\sum (-1)^na_n=\sum \frac1n$ which diverges

Answer (score 3):

No, this is in general wrong. Consider for instance $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Harmonic series can be counterexample for your statement. So no, it’s not true.

Answer (score 1):

$a_k= \frac 1k$ if $k$ even $a_k= -\frac 1{k-1}$ is $k$ odd

$\sum (-1)^ka_k = \sum \frac 1{k}$ diverges but $\sum  a_k =  \frac1{2n} $ converges

Your result is true is all $a_k$ are positive in the first place or if the |a_k| serie converges